I want to merge geojson's adjacent grids into one large grid based on properties. What should I do?


I tried using gdal：
bash

docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/data ghcr.io/osgeo/gdal:alpine-normal-latest \
    ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON /data/Zones_merged.geojson /data/Zones_smoothed.geojson \
    -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry, AVG(DEPTH2D) AS DEPTH2D \
                          FROM Zones AS a \
                          WHERE EXISTS (
                              SELECT 1 FROM Zones AS b
                              WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(a.geometry, 0.1), b.geometry)
                                AND ABS(a.DEPTH2D - b.DEPTH2D) <= 15
                          ) \
                          GROUP BY a.rowid"

I have also used Python and GeoPandas.
